# Dumping the JQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I have been learning about js objects for work, so I decided to see what happens if I tried to break down the jQuery object into its components. I wanted to know if there is a better and more granular way to do this, or if there are some other tricks that could be educational:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>JQuery Dump</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            ol li {
                font-weight:bold
            }
            ol li ul {
                margin-bottom:0px
            }
            ol li ul li {
                display:inline-block;
            }
            ol li ul li {
                font-weight:normal;
                list-style:none;
                margin-right:8px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ol>
            <script>
                var x = "";
                for(var i in jQuery) {
                    x += ("<li>" + i + "<ul>");
                    for(var j in jQuery[i]) {
                        x += ("<li><pre>" + j + "</pre></li>");
                    }
                    x += ("</ul></li>");
                }
                document.write(x);
            </script>
        </ol>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: For a quick and easy way to inspect a jQuery object, you could just log it. If you open up Firebug or Chrome developer tools, select the console tab, and enter `console.log(jqObject)`, it will print out the object with all of its properties. It will display triangles beside properties to expand them and further inspect its contents.

Comment: I've updated my answer to produce an output that is closer to what you are starting with (but recursive)

Comment: Also notice that many of the properties you will find are for internal use or offer very advanced extensibility. For learning jQuery, you should have a look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/), for learning about jQuery you might read [its code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a great opportunity to learn about recursive functions.  Here is concise example taken from 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7102330/16959) that I have adapted to better match your question ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z2TrM/2/)).

```
<div id="Tree"></div>
```

With the following JavaScript:

```
var tree = $('#Tree');
function r(obj) {
    var html = "<ul>";
    if (obj)
        for (var key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] == "object")
                html += '<li>'+key+':'+r(obj[key])+'</li>';
            else if (typeof obj[key] != "function")
                html +='<li>'+key+':'+obj[key]+'</li>';
            else
                html +='<li>'+key+'()</li>';
        }
    html += "</ul>";
    return html;
} 

$('#Tree').html(r(jQuery));

r(jQuery);
```

Comment: You should use `'<li>'+key+': '+r(obj[key])+'</li>'`

Comment: +1, good suggestion @Bergi, updated answer, jsfiddle will have to wait (on my iPhone)

Comment: The grade is "A". I have done recursion once before but wasn't sure what was the best approach for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to take a peek into the jQuery object you could just use `console.dir` to interact with the object.  For example, open your console and type `console.dir($)`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/console.dir

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing above code and printing this code on html page you should simply try `console.dir($)` and see your console screen.