# How to iterate through nested json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have very complex json created at server side 
like -

```
{"2013": {"11": {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6}, "12": {"A": 0, "B": 281, "C": 5}}, "2014": {"1": {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6}}}
```

Above JSON object holds the values 'A','B', and 'C' for the three months i.e current + last 2months

```
var data = {{=monthly_result}}; //Python variable assigned to js var
```

Now I want to loop through the above object in javascript.
Please guide me.
Found many links but not any is fully helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Google Javascript Loops

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to read an object's properties while using a recursive function in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102182/how-to-read-an-objects-properties-while-using-a-recursive-function-in-javascrip)

Comment: Iterate and do what? Transform it into a new value, annotate objects with additional properties?

Comment: `{{=monthly_result}};` ???

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for loop, here's a very simple example :

```
var data = {"2013": {"11": {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6}, "12": 
           {"A": 0, "B": 281, "C": 5}}, "2014": {"1": 
           {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6}}};

for(var year in data) {
    var ydata = data[year];
    for(var num in ydata) {
        var ndata = ydata[num];
        for(var l in ndata) {
            console.log(year + ' -> ' + num + ' -> ' + l + ' = ' + ndata[l]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working...BUT when I am assigning my json to obj like - var obj = {{=monthly_result}} ......its giving some error. Any help around that Please.

Comment: @user3020422 instead of commenting here and there update your question with requirement

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over a "complex" object in a generic way, I would proceed like this :

```
(psedo code to show how it could be done)

var result = [];
function objIterate(obj, i) {
   result.push([]);
   for (prop in obj){
      if (isObj(prop))
         objIterate(prop, i+1);
      else
         result[i].push(obj[prop]);
   }
}

var obj = yourJson;
objIterate(obj, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

### Do something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/b8k7Y/2/)

```
var obj = {"2013": {
            "11": {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6},
            "12": {"A": 0, "B": 281, "C": 5}
            }, 
          "2014": 
            {"1": {"A": 0, "B": 310, "C": 6}
           }
        };

for(outer in obj) {
    for (inner in obj[outer]) {
        for(innermost in obj[item][inner]) {
            alert(outer + "-->" + inner + "-->" + innermost + "-->" + obj[item][inner][innermost]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Its working...BUT when I am assigning my json to obj like - var obj = {{=monthly_result}} ......its giving some error. Any help around that Please.

Comment: @user3020422 can you please open a new question for this or just edit above..And if this is working please mark this as correct.Also check fiddle I also assigned json to variable obj